# pop up search having issues with checkbox filters

Tags: sugarcrm

I have to select leads while scheduling a meeting in the "related to" field. A popup is generated when I click the "arrow mark" icon. The results fetched after clicking on submit button are not matching the filters used.

When I navigate to second page, I have seen that checkbox queries are getting applied, for instance, checkbox1=0&checkbox2=0&checkbox3=0 is getting appended to the url.

I would like to remove this extra checkbox related query from the url so that my search works properly. Please provide guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question needs to be clear and concise. Mention here if you have done any customization in sugarbean.php file or into the meeting module.

Comment: I have done customizations to both sugarbean.php and for files in meeting module. But these changes are in no way related to pop up related query.
Please tell me how to remove the checkbox params from url in the pop up search.